# Rails 6 ActiveStorage revert transactions on file upload failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-activestorage

I have a pretty simple scenario, i am creating a record, and than attaching a file(after `save!`, because i need id on the record to generate finename of the attachment), all of this is wrapped in a transaction.

Something like:

```
def create
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    record = A.create!(a_params)
    pdf = generate_pdf
    record.file.attach(
      io: StringIO.new(pdf),
      filename: "PO##{record.id}.pdf",
      content_type: 'application/pdf'
    )
  rescue
    # here it should rollback transaction on all kind of errors, if it fails upload or whatever, but it does not
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

But activestorage uploads file only after commit has occurred, so this inner rescue never works, what works is:

```
def create
  record = nil
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    record = A.create!(a_params)
    pdf = generate_pdf
    record.file.attach(
      io: StringIO.new(pdf),
      filename: "PO##{record.id}.pdf",
      content_type: 'application/pdf'
    )
  end
rescue
  record&.destroy!
end
```

Here i have simplified this scenario, in reality I have a scenario where a lot of records are being created in a loop, and i dont want to save any of those in case of any error.

I found some issue like:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32449
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31985

How can i fix this in best way, i read that **active storage uploads files in background to not make transaction live long**. Because that will create problems otherwise. Which makes sense, and i think i should also put pdf_generation logic out of the transaction.

But **I want to know if there is any better way on this to create records only if pdf is generated + uploaded correctly. Instead of manually destroying them and reverting any other updates to DB in case of an error.**

Answer (score 6):

I have found an alternative, that still elegantly validates the upload.

First you upload the file with the method `ActiveStorage::Blob.create_after_upload!`, passing some file params as **io**, **filename** and **content_type**:
https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveStorage/Blob/create_after_upload%21/class

And then, you set and save the `blob` uploaded to the attachment column.

In your case, could be like this:

```
blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_after_upload!(
  io: StringIO.new(pdf), 
  filename: "PO##{record.id}.pdf",
  content_type: 'application/pdf')

record.file = blob
record.save!
```

On this way, if any error occurs during the file upload to the service, it will be raised before and inside of the current block, as initially expected.

NOTE: It was tested on Rails version 6.0.x, so I don`t know if it works well on other versions.

Comment: great find, how did you come upon this method?